# What's the tool used by Debian Jessie installer to configure wifi?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-wheezy, debian-jessie, command-line-tool

I just installed Debian Jessie. During the installation procedure, wireless network configuration is done in command line mode. The tool which assist the wifi network setup is pretty simple, it just does what needs to be done. Let me explain, it presents a list of all the networks available and then asks for the password.

Now that the system is installed I need to configure wifi. I did a very basic installation (in a usb drive, less then 1GB) and I'm in command line.

Question: What's the tool that assisted me during the installation? I would like to use it again to setup wifi.

In case someone knows another simple tool to assist the wifi setup in command line mode, I would appreciate very much to know.

Answer (score 2):

The network connections are configured during installation with the [netcfg](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/netcfg) Debian-Installer component. This package is not intended for installation on a normal Debian system.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92810/60293) for some hints on what tools you can use.